# Ruby difference in two string arrays and pass to the method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got following array of strings with nicknames of owners:

```
OWNERS = %w[test1 test2 test3].freeze
```

I want to detect any differences in the list of owners (e.g. when new user was granted owner role). To do so I'm getting list of `current_owners` which represents array of strings:

```
current_owners = %w[test1 test2 test3]
```

How to fetch changes when `current_owners` will be not the same as `OWNERS` and pass this difference to another method?

Example:

```
OWNERS = %w[test1 test2 test3].freeze
current_owners = %w[test1 test2 test3 newuser test10]
```

I want to pass `'newuser'` and `test10` as a parameter to the method `new_owner_alarm(string)` to be like `new_owner_alarm('newuser')`, `new_owner_alarm('test10')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(current_owners - OWNERS).each { |new_owner| new_owner_alarm(new_owner) }
```